# How to overload a class with an Image (Android)

Tags: android, android-emulator, overloading

I am new in android app development and right now I have a problem with overloading a class.

I want to overload and integer, a String, an Image and a boolean. 
I know how to overload the int and the String but how I can overload an Image img?

```
    public class Test(int n, String[] TestString, Image img <---- how to do it ?, boolean inTest)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Is `Image` your custom class?

Comment: No it isn't my question is how I can overload an image.
The image img is only an example how I thought how to do it.